# Docusign JWT authentication dotnet core issue

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

I need to get access token in docusign with JWT Grant.In there I'm confusing with signature part.
Here is the way I did
First created token

```
 var token = new JwtBuilder()
                         .WithAlgorithm(new HMACSHA256Algorithm())
                         .WithSecret(privateKey)
                         .AddClaim("iss", clientId)
                         .AddClaim("sub", accountId)
                         .AddClaim("iat", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeSeconds())
                         .AddClaim("aud", aud)
                         .AddClaim("scope", "signature impersonation")
                         .Encode();
```

In here PrivateKey of docusign added as Secret.

Here is the postman request

```
url: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
body: {
    "grant_type":"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "assertion":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI4YzNkMDM0My01ZGQzLTQ3YjQtOWFkZi1iNjYxNTc4NjRmOWYiLCJzdWIiOiIwOWRjMWE4OC03Zjk1LTQ3Y2YtYTJkOC00NzQxYTc0N2E2NzUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDM4Nzg3OTIsImF1ZCI6ImFjY291bnQtZC5kb2N1c2lnbi5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6InNpZ25hdHVyZSBpbXBlcnNvbmF0aW9uIn0.QmbBst9_QOW9vZlI1CnVaUmv3AlNeWItRnPNiCE7vZ4"
}
method: post
```

It returning bad request.Here is the error message

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "no_valid_keys_or_signatures"
}
```

How to resolve this please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue
Issue way JWT token signature is not a valid algorithm.And I had to add docusign app private key to add.
I stored private key inside a file called private.key
Here is the code

```
 var privateKeyfilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "SignDocuments", "private.key");
            string privateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(privateKeyfilePath);
            var rsaPrivate = RSA.Create();
            rsaPrivate.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), out _);
            var privateKeyRSA = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaPrivate);
            SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateKeyRSA, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

            var claims = new Claim[]
           {
                new Claim("iss", clientId),
                new Claim("sub", APIUsername),
                new Claim("iat", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()+ ""),
                new Claim("aud", aud),
                new Claim("scope", "signature impersonation"),
           };

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials,
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                issuer: clientId
                );
```

After that we have to obtain consent for internal application.
For that use this [url](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5000/Account/Document). replace clientId with your one

Remember to add same redirect url inside your app created in docusign.
and url scope need to be scope=signature%20impersonation (both signature and impersonation need)

After that docusign asking to accept it.

You can check if your app already obtain consent in docusign manage profile under Connected Apps

Finally you can get access token

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you consider using our [QuickStart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart), which will set everything up for you and use the C# SDK. It is already .NET Core.
After you run it, it's first Auth Code Grant.
To change to JWT you can modify the config where it says quickstart="true" to "false" or you can logout and back in using JWT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But this not the one I expected.However I have resolved that. thanks again